# PHP Equivalent of Master page in ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net

Is there any way to achieve the master page concept of ASP.NET in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/):

> Although Smarty is known as a
>   "Template Engine", it would be more
>   accurately described as a
>   "Template/Presentation Framework."
>   That is, it provides the programmer
>   and template designer with a wealth of
>   tools to automate tasks commonly dealt
>   with at the presentation layer of an
>   application.

Answer (score 20):

Of course it's possible. Have a look [here](http://hoolihan.net/blog-tim/?p=48). It shows a basic way of doing it, which of course, you can extend. Good luck!

Comment: This looks simple! Good one for naive users :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) together with [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: I like output buffering as an easy, effective solution. Here's a guide that shows how to approximate master pages using output buffering - http://spinningtheweb.blogspot.com/2006/07/approximating-master-pages-in-php.html

Comment: Definitely the best answer (with addition from @Dan :) )

Answer (score 5):

I made a simple proof-of-concept for a asp-like master pages in PHP. You can get it here:
http://code.google.com/p/phpmasterpages/

Answer (score 4):

As other said, the way to go is to use a template engine. My preference goes to the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), which is a bit more than just templates ;), but has a nice implementation of a layout with [Zend_Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html) that is very close to Master Pages in ASP.Net.

Check the [quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) to have an idea of how this works, and have a look [at the full doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) to see the possibilities offered by the framework. Plus, using the framework gives you a nice MVC architecture and SEO-friends rewritten URLs...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use include() since the variables in both file are in the same scope. Also ob_start() can record the output to the buffer so that the html codes can output later.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to do is using include as other said. Create a header.php and footer.php and include them in every page you want to use. The approach is bit different compare to asp.net master pages but is as powerful as master pages